# Не могу получить параметры запроса bodyParser

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa.js

Пишу свой первый backend для базы данных RethinkDB и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу разобрать запрос в bodyParser

Вот мой код:

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const logger = require('koa-morgan')
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')
const Router = require('koa-router')
const r = require('rethinkdb')

const server = new Koa()
const router = new Router()

const db = async() => {
    const connection = await r.connect({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '28015',
        db: 'getteamDB'
    })
    return connection;
}

server.use(bodyParser());
server
.use(router.routes())
.use(logger('tiny')).listen(3001)


const getUsers = async(ctx, next) => {
    await next()

  // Get the db connection.
  const connection = await db()

  // Check if a table exists.
  var exists = await r.tableList().contains('users').run(connection)
  if (exists === false) {
    ctx.throw(500, 'users table does not exist')
  }

  // Retrieve documents.
  var cursor = await r.table('users')
    .run(connection)

  var users = await cursor.toArray()

  ctx.type = 'json'
  ctx.body = users
}

const insertUser = async(ctx, next) => {
    await next()
    // Get the db connection.
    const connection = await db()

    // Throw the error if the table does not exist.
    var exists = await r.tableList().contains('users').run(connection)
    if (exists === false) {
      ctx.throw(500, 'users table does not exist')
    }

    let body = ctx.request.body || {}

    console.log('получаем имя в запросе - ', body);

    // Throw the error if no name.
    if (body.name === undefined) {
      ctx.throw(400, 'name is required')
    }

    // Throw the error if no email.
    if (body.email === undefined) {
      ctx.throw(400, 'email is required')
    }

    let document = {
      name: body.name,
      email: body.email
    }

    var result = await r.table('users')
      .insert(document, {returnChanges: true})
      .run(connection)

    ctx.body = result
  }

router
.get('/users', getUsers)
.post('/users', insertUser)
```

Метод getUsers работает нормально, возвращает пустой массив (БД пустая)
Метод insertUser не может получить body из роута.

Подскажите, где ошибка

Консоль лог пишет {}
А логгер пишет 'name is required'

Answer (score 0):

Вместо:

```
  let body = ctx.request.body || {}
```

использовал:

```
 let body = ctx.request.query || {}
```

Помогло решение в этом [топике на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437961/why-bodyparser-returns-undefined).